# Possible to code a component (Aura or LWC) and see it in local?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, vs-code, sfdx-plugin

So far, while coding a component (Aura, or LWC), we need everytime to deploy to the org to see modifications, is there a way to code in my local machine ? (localhost like) ?

In Angular for example if I want to change text color for example, the change is quasi-instantly ? (no action is needed to see the change).

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need [LWC Local Development](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2019/10/announcing-lwc-local-development-beta.html).